# How to install an OSX Leopard ISO on a hard drive through another mac?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, iso-image

I have an OLD PowerPC-based Mac G5 on which i am attempting to install OSX 10.5 Leopard.

I only have an ISO and no DL DVD to burn it onto. Moreover the tower doesn't recognize an OSX installation USB with 10.5.

I do, however, have another mac and a HDD Dock. Is there a way for me to install the Leopard ISO directly on to the drive through my other mac(intel-based)?

Comment: Is the secondary mac a PPC?

Comment: @nerdwaller  My second Mac is a Mac Mini 2.5GHz Intel Core i5 With OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103343/installing-osx-onto-ppc-using-intel-mac-and-firewire) may be helpful.  Though it may require you to get extra cables if you don't own them.

Answer (score 0):

If both your Macs have firewire ports then you should be able to connect the old PPC G5 Mac (Mac 1) to your other Mac (Mac 2) via a firewire cable.

Power up Mac 2 first, then with both Macs connected via Firewire power up Mac 1 while holding down the T key. This will start it in Target Disk Mode and the hard drive of Mac 1 should be automatically mounted and available to read/write as an external volume on Mac 2 - just the same as if you had connected a firewire drive.

You can then use Disk Utility or Carbon Copy Cloner or similar to clone the ISO image to the mounted hard drive.